# Detecting for invalid file inputs, Python

Tags: python, input, raiserror

I have an assignment to write a Python script which "detects whether the file is readable or not".

I am stuck as to which exceptions I should run. Let's say the input file is intended to be a text file, with extension `*.txt`

What is the exception I should raise? I suspect there should be multiple. At the moment, I have:

```
with open('example_file.txt") as textfile:
        if not textfile.lower().endswith('.txt'):
            raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(
                'Not a text file! Argument filename must be of type *.txt')
        return textfile
```

However, that only checks the file extension. What else could I possibly check? What is the standard for file I/O in Python?

Comment: What do you mean by readable? Does it mean the file exists? Does it mean the file only contains printable characters (such as ascii ones)? Does it mean that you have the proper permissions to read from the file?

Comment: Also, the extension will not have an effect on python's ability to read a file.

Comment: Why would a csv file have to have a .csv extension?

Comment: @Jon That's what I don't understand. I have no idea what it meant by "raise an error if the file is not readable". The only thought I had if to check for extensions. Are there other checks I could put in place to make this person happy?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Bad example. I am using a text file instead.

Comment: I think you need to figure out what your assignment is. I mentioned a couple of different things in my first comment that you could do.

Comment: @ShanZhengYang the extension is irrelevant, the only way a file would be unreadable would be permissions errors or encoding problems etc.. the extension does not matter. I imagine you should be catching errors in relation to that. There are specific errno's that are relevant, https://docs.python.org/2/library/errno.html

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I think it means "this program only runs on text files". If the user inputs a .pdf or a .ppt, raise an error. Is that reasonable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check whether the file *exists*:

```
import os.path
if os.path.exists('example_file.txt'):
    print('it exists!')
```

Beyond this, successfully `open`ing the file will demonstrate *readability*. The built-in `open` raises an `IOError` exception if it fails. Failure can occur for more than one reason, so we must check whether it failed due to readability:

```
import errno
try:
    textfile = open('example_file.txt', 'r')
    textfile.close()
    print("file is readable")
except IOError as e:
    if e.errno == errno.EACCES:
        print("file exists, but isn't readable")
    elif e.errno == errno.ENOENT:
        print("files isn't readable because it isn't there")
```

The [relevant section of the docs on file permissions.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.access) Note that the use of `os.access` to check readability before calling `open` is discouraged.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham If I can open a file in mode "r" that means it is readable. Permission checking is done at the time you open the file. (It does obviously not mean the file's contents are valid or can be interpreted by my program.)

Comment: @SebastianRiese,  yes and that is a requirement, the file must be a text file, are you saying opening the file means that it is?

Comment: `os.R_OK` is just testing for read permissions which you can and should catch in  the try checking for it with  `if e.errno == errno.EACCES`. https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#files-and-directories

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thanks for the clarifications. Does this look accurate now?

Comment: yep, the first is subject to a race condition but probably not relevant to the OP,  also maybe `except IOError as e` so it will work for 2 and 3